# NWJS Aapp icon on taskbar is making a new instance of the icon next to the original on the task bar?

Tags: nwjs

I don't know if im using the wrong size favicon from my package.json or what? I also used resource hacker to change the icon of the nwjs.exe app with the same icon but an ico of all standard sizes. I also tried using and ico of the favicon instead of a png at a particular size but it still give the same problem? Mayne not link to an icon from the manifest at all since I change the icon of the exe with resource hacker? Some apps I've made it didn't do this at all and then randomly on other projects it does this. I even tried making a shortcut of the nwjs.exe app and using the shortcut on the task bar and it still does it. Any ideas on why this behavior is happening?

If I can provide any other details to help resolve this let me know and I will add via edits to my post.

[The way it should behave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap9Nq.png)

[Before I launch app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtmjw.png)

[After I launch app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdpB0.png)

Ive tried different size pngs for the favicon ive also tried using a ico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you pinned an executable that launches another executable.

1. Click on the icon in the task bar
2. The app will load
3. Right-click on the left icon > Unpin from taskbar
4. Right-click on the remaining (right) icon > Pin to task bar
5. Close your app
6. Wait a couple of seconds
7. Click on the icon

Did that work? If not, right-click on the icon > right-click on your app name in the context menu > properties. What is the "Target" value.

Comment: Worked. I keep getting the issue I don't know why it's happening. I'm dragging the program file itself directly to the taskbar.